# recycler view null pointer exception while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Trying to list accelerometer x, y,z data in `RecyclerView`. Below is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv); // layout reference

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
//        rv.setHasFixedSize(true); // to improve performance

        rv.setAdapter(dataAdapter = new DataManager()); // the data manager is assigner to the RV
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
                new RecyclerClickListener(this, new RecyclerClickListener.MyOnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // STUB:
                        // The click on the item must be handled
                    }
                }));
    }
```

The `DataManager` class stores the data

```
public class DataManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataManager.RecyclerViewHolder>
{
ArrayList<AccelData> myDataStore = new ArrayList<AccelData>();

public ArrayList<AccelData> getMyDataStore() {
    return myDataStore;
}


    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView content;
        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView)
        {

            super(itemView);
            content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_element ,viewGroup,false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder,int i)
    {
        viewHolder.content.setText("X = "+myDataStore.get(i).getX()+" ; Y = "+myDataStore.get(i).getY()+" ; Z = "+myDataStore.get(i).getZ());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return myDataStore.size();
    }

    static class AccelData {
        private double x,y,z;

        AccelData(double x,double y, double z){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public void setX(double x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(double y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setZ(double z) {
            this.z = z;
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public double getZ() {
            return z;
        }
    }

}
```

onSensorChanged the data is populated as below

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
    {

        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
        if(mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            Log.e("changed",+x+":"+y+":"+z);
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(curTime-lastUpdate>100)
            {
                diffTime = (curTime-lastUpdate);
                lastUpdate = curTime;
            }
            float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
            if(speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD)
            {
                dataAdapter.getMyDataStore().add(new DataManager.AccelData(x,y,z));
                dataAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataAdapter.getMyDataStore().size()-1);
//                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;
        }

    }
```

and this is the log

```
04-21 10:04:03.818: E/changed(11766): -507.006:-586.466:-476.383
04-21 10:04:03.912: I/Choreographer(11766): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 10:04:03.972: I/Choreographer(11766): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 10:04:04.620: E/changed(11766): -60.9322:-408.35:-580.506
04-21 10:04:05.067: I/Choreographer(11766): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 10:04:05.156: I/Choreographer(11766): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 10:04:05.247: I/Choreographer(11766): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 10:04:05.280: E/InputEventReceiver(11766): Exception dispatching input event.
04-21 10:04:05.299: D/AndroidRuntime(11766): Shutting down VM
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766): Process: com.example.nagarajan.myapplication, PID: 11766
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.getBridge()' on a null object reference
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:923)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:1343)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.addViewHolderToRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.java:3900)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleCachedViewAt(RecyclerView.java:3843)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:3880)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:3804)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleViewAt(RecyclerView.java:5529)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:1139)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleViewsFromStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1244)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1268)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1102)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:959)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1047)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:1768)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
04-21 10:04:05.358: E/AndroidRuntime(11766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
```

Comment: Checked this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29163107/1160282

Comment: @SilentKiller, I think tat is irrelevant. Because I tried with rev 21 lib also

Comment: how you populate data to your adapter

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam, Sorry, please see the edit

Comment: looks like your supportv4 and rv versions are not sync. Update both to the latest and issue will disappear.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?